# Two vectors closed to a third vectors. What can we know about the inner product of these two vector?

Tags: inequality, vectors, inner-products

Consider in a space of unknown dimension, all we know is that vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$ are both very "close" to $\vec{w}$. To be more specific, they have inner-products $|\langle\vec{v},\vec{w}\rangle|\geq\delta$ and $|\langle\vec{u},\vec{w}\rangle|\geq\delta$. The three vectors are normalized. Can we infer a lower bound on $|\langle\vec{v},\vec{u}\rangle|$ based on this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "close"

Comment: @DonThousand The OP explained that using the inequalities involving $\delta$ above.  Effectively, the "angle" between them (*defined according to the specific inner product used*) is within some set distance to zero.  @ Shuai, can you show that the angle between your first two vectors can be at most twice the angle between each of the original vectors and the third?

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah I thought that was separate. Got it.

Comment: @Macavity how?  Take $\delta = 1$ for instance... that directly implies that $u=v=w$.  Now, consider $\delta = 1-\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon>0$... Perhaps you missed that $u,v,w$ are all unit vectors.

Comment: @JMoravitz. True for that specific case.  However say for $\delta =\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and 2D, we can see the unit vectors $u=i, v=j $ and $w = (i+j)/\sqrt2$ work.  If we have a bound, I suppose it should work for all cases of allowable $\delta$?

Comment: @Macavity and that is fine for *that* specific case.  We have talked about the two trivial cases so far... where the angle between them is large enough that twice that angle is greater than or equal to $90^\circ$ or where the angle between them is small enough that the angle is necessarily zero.  How about for $\delta = 0.999$?  There is surely a lower bound for $|\langle u,v\rangle|$ which is what the OP is asking about.  Given a predefined preselected value of $\delta$, find a bound on $|\langle u,v\rangle|$

Comment: Ah..  we need the bound in terms of $\delta$.  Seems simply $|2\delta^2-1|$ from cosine addition rules,

Comment: Using the claim that the angle between $u$ and $v$ must be at most twice the angle between $u$ and $w$ or $v$ and $w$ which we know to be related to $\arccos(\delta)$, we'd have $|\langle u,v\rangle |\geq \cos(2\arccos(\delta))$.  I'm not confident that I can prove this however for arbitrary inner product spaces.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thank you for the reminding! Yes, that works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the additional assumption that the inner product space $H$ is *complete* (i.e. a Hilbert space) over $K=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ we can use the [existence of an orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections) $P$ onto the linear subspace generated by $w$. Then
$$
 u = Pu + (I-P)u = u_1 w + a \quad \text{with } u_1 \in K, \, a \in H, \,\langle a, w \rangle = 0 \, ,\\
 v = Pv + (I-P)v = v_1 w + b \quad \text{with } v_1 \in K, \,b \in H, \,\langle b, w \rangle = 0 \, .\\
$$
It follows that
$$
|u_1| = |\langle u, w \rangle| \ge \delta \, , \\
|v_1| = |\langle v, w \rangle| \ge \delta \, , \\
$$
and
$$
\langle u, v \rangle = u_1 \overline{v_1} + \langle a, b \rangle
$$
because the mixed terms are zero. Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the Pythagorean theorem we get
$$
|\langle u, v \rangle| \ge |u_1 v_1| - \Vert a \Vert \cdot \Vert b \Vert
= |u_1 v_1| - \sqrt{1 - |u_1|^2} \cdot \sqrt{1 - |v_1|^2}
\\ \ge \delta^2 - (1 - \delta^2) = 2 \delta^2 - 1 \, .
$$
This a “nontrivial” estimate if $\delta > 1/\sqrt 2$, and in particular $|\langle u, v \rangle|$ is close to one if $\delta $ is close to one.